# Omniauth+Devise+Facebook = An error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

I followed these instructions verbatim: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "xxx", "yyy", :scope => 'email,offline_access,read_stream', :display => 'popup'
```

The View link works and it asks me to Sign In with Facebook. However, when clicking it, I get **"An error occurred. Please try again later."**. No other information or errors.

In my facebook app, 'app domain' is not set, and site URL is set to 'localhost:3000'.

My gut is telling me there is something wrong with that configuration/callback, however localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback works fine.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** When I try the login while logged in to the Facebook account that owns the app, it works perfectly. When I try with a different Facebook account, this error fires.

**EDIT 2:** Figured it out http://cl.ly/D6st

Answer (score 1):

Go to your facebook application's settings set `sandbox`to `disable`

Thats all.